# What does "\lettrine" do?

Tags: lettrine

I have seen the command a few times and I want to know what `\lettrine` does and whether you have to use a package in order for it to work.

Answer (score 25):

From the [lettrine](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettrine) package documentation:

> Adding `\usepackage{lettrine}` in the preamble of a document defines the
>   command `\lettrine`, the simplest use of which is
>   `\lettrine{<letter>}{<text>}`. It produces a dropped capital `<letter>` (2
>   lines high), followed by  typeset in small caps, and the rest of
>   the paragraph is wrapped around the dropped capital.

A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[lraise=0.1, nindent=0em, slope=-.5em]{V}{oici} un exemple \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Drop caps *are* an _essential_ feature of typesetting programs; I'm surprised LaTeX didn't have native support.

Comment: Your screenshot shows both a lettrine *and* a semi-prominent typographic river. Neat! :-)

Comment: it is unfortunate that this solution requires mixing text and formatting; I would have really like a global setting to affect every letter after a chapter header.

Answer (score 2):

From the [here](http://modules.contextgarden.net/dl/t-lettrine/doc/context/third/lettrine/lettrine-doc.pdf) ! You can find a short introduction for the package and also some exemples showing how you can use it.

---

Malek B.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think you should elaborate on your answer. Link-only answers tend to become invalid most likely on a long term view

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\lettrine[lines=2]{C}{LOUD}
```

will work

Comment: Maybe you can show the output to illustrate what it really does?