# How to format the first letter of a word differently?

Tags: formatting, packages

I'm looking for a command, which would take a text and print it with the first letter formatted differently:

```
\first{Hello, world!}
```

Should be turned into:

```
\textbf{\large H}ello, world!
```

Is there a package, which would do this?

Comment: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52743/what-does-lettrine-do]

Comment: The [lettrine](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettrine) package

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda `\lettrine{H}{ello, world!}` is not what I'm looking for, since `ello, world!` will trigger my spell checker

Comment: is the example  represnttaive with a latin H? that is a single token so easy to pick up, deciding twhat is the first letter is rather harder if you have non ascii letters such as Cyrillic or accented characters which are several tokens in UTF-8 if you use pdftex but still single toikens if you are using luatex or xetex

Comment: for the simple cases: `\newcommand\foo[1]{\textbf{\large #1}}` ,,,, `\foo Hello, world`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the only aversion to `lettrine` is breaking your spell checker, then just bundle it inside another macro, `\first`.

**PDFLATEX**

Since the OP asked about pdflatex in another comment, I introduce `\pervyy`, which bundles the 2-byte letter sequence that makes up Cyrillic characters, for use in `\lettrine`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\newcommand\first[1]{\firstaux#1\relax}
\def\firstaux#1#2\relax{\lettrine{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\pervyy[1]{\pervyyaux#1\relax}
\def\pervyyaux#1#2#3\relax{\lettrine{#1#2}{#3}}
\begin{document}
\first{This} is a test of using\\
lettrine without breaking \\
the spell-check features.

\pervyy{Привет,} мир!
\end{document}
```

[image]

**LUALATEX OR XELATEX**

If one wanted to use an engine other than pdflatex, then omit the `T2A` encoding, load an appropriate font supporting the Cyrillic alphabet, and just use `\first`, regardless of which alphabet is employed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond} % choose a suitable text font
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\newcommand\first[1]{\firstaux#1\relax}
\def\firstaux#1#2\relax{\lettrine{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\first{This} is a test of using\\
lettrine without breaking \\
the spell-check features.

\first{Привет,} мир!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you're willing and able to compile your document with LuaLaTeX, the following solution may be of interest to you.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond} % choose a suitable text font

\usepackage{luacode} % for "\luaexec" macro
\luaexec{
  function first ( s )
    local t
    t = "\\textbf{\\large " .. unicode.utf8.sub(s,1,1) .. "}"
    tex.sprint (  t .. unicode.utf8.sub(s,2) )
  end
}
\newcommand\first[1]{\luaexec{ first ( "#1" ) }}

\begin{document}
\first{Hello, world!}

\first{Привет, мир!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks. I've updated the code to handle the case of `\first{Привет, мир!}`. The main change, I think, consisted of loading the `fontspec` package and loading a text font that contains Cyrillic characters. :-)

Comment: thanks :-)......

Comment: Is it at all possible to do the same (or similar) in pdflatex?

Comment: Of course there's the challenge of correctly handling, say A + ´ or other Unicode glyphs that are built out of combining characters, for example ‍‍ is actually five unicode characters, or क्‍ which is three (ka + virāma + ZWJ). (the semantics of ZWJ are their own little mess. In Emjoi contexts it's infix, but for Indic scripts, it's (mostly) postfix.

Comment: @yegor256 - LaTeX3 provides a pretty good string library, but I haven't mastered LaTeX3 (yet). But I'm pretty good with Lua and LuaTeX...

Comment: @DonHosek - I may have interpreted the OP's criterion, "the first letter of a word", to narrowly. :-)